# Problems printing transparency pngs with printjob (Flash AS)

Tags: flash, actionscript, printing, png, transparency

I am trying to print a movieclip with printjob in flash.

This movieclip contains two layers: one with a PNG image with transparency and one below with a jpg image.

The problem is that the transparency of the png is not respected so the jpg image does not appear.

The code i'm using is real simple:

```
var my_pj:PrintJob = new PrintJob();

if (my_pj.start()) {
    my_pj.addPage("_parent.imprimir", {xMin:0, xMax:399, yMin:0, yMax:900}, false);
    my_pj.send();
}
delete my_pj;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same problem, need to have some transparent pngs and vectors in my PrintJob. Adobe says to use:

```
var options:PrintJobOptions = new PrintJobOptions();
options.printAsBitmap = true;
myPrintJob.addPage(mySprite, null, options);
```

BUT on a Mac we get a blank page for the print UNLESS you have the Object on the Stage. Thanks goes to Craig Grummitt's Before I Forget Blog posting for the solution!! 
http://craiggrummitt.wordpress.com/2007/12/21/printasbitmap-object-must-be-on-stage

```
this.addChild(page);
//for macs only – otherwise they display the page while the print dialogue is open.
page.visible = false; 
var myOption:PrintJobOptions = new PrintJobOptions(true);
my_pj.addPage(page, null, myOption);
my_pj.send();
this.removeChild(page);
```

I'm just hiding the Object that I need to print, this solution works great for me. I've got a symbol in the Library that I'm exporting. I've got transparent PNGs with my vectors.

addPage first parameter is a Sprite, so I couldn't figure out how to make corneliu's solution work.

Comment: To use Corneliu solution just create the bitmap, add it to a sprite, and just print that sprite.

Answer (score 1):

Take a screenshot of your movieclip:

```
var bmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(_parent.imprimir.width, _parent.imprimir.height);
bmp.draw(_parent.imprimir);
var page:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmp);
```

This technique is recommended for every printjob, because you can apply all sorts of transformations to the bitmap (scale, rotate, smoothing etc.) before sending it to the printer.

Comment: except vectors quality will be lost?

Comment: @alxx What do you mean? He is going to print the movieclip anyway, what would he need vectors for? Not to mention that in the question, he stated clearly that he has a png and a jpg, not vectors.

Comment: I just noted that rasterizing probably not the best for *every* print job, although for this case this is correct.